# Trying to get property of non-object the error focuses on <td>'.$users->username.'</td>

Tags: php, laravel

I'm having this error please can anyone help?

> Trying to get property of non-object the error focuses on `<td>'.$users->username.'</td>`

Below is my code that has an error:

```
function GetactivationReq() 
{
    $settings = DB::table('settings')->where('id', 1)->first();    
    $users = DB::table('activationFee')->orderBy('id', 'desc')->get();
    foreach ($users as $row) {   
        $users = DB::table('users')->where('id', $row->sender_id)->first();
        $receiver = DB::table('users')->where('id', $row->receiver_id)->first();
        $user = DB::table('userdetails')->where('userid', $row->sender_id)->first();
        echo '<tr>
            <th><input type="checkbox" class="select-all" value="1"></th>
            <td>'.$users->username.'</td>
            <td>'.$user->accountname.'</td>
            <td>'.$receiver->username.'</td>
            <td>'.$settings->currency.''.$row->amount.'</td>
            <td>'.$row->payment_status.'</td>
          </tr>';
    }
}
```

Comment: you have two variable same name `$users` .. so change variable name..

Comment: please can you add lines of code for me

Comment: Please tag appropriately - there isn’t any `regex` involved anywhere in the code you have shown. (Tag removed.)

Comment: _“please can you add lines of code for me”_ - are you _serious_ right now? All you need to do is use a different name for the variable inside the loop body, because otherwise you are _overwriting_ the $users variable you are actually trying to loop over.

Comment: change  `$users   = DB::table('users')->where('id', $row->sender_id)->first();` as `$usersDetail` and access as a `$usersDetail->useraneme`

Comment: it didnt work still throwing the same error

Comment: check data exist or not `return $usersDetail->useraneme`

Comment: in your question there is a lot of syntax error .. you did not close `}}` for function and foreach..

Comment: yes it does exits and it returns the correct output, buh many return syntax appeared at the top

Comment: `$users` is a multidimensional array cause your query have multiple matches therefore, you need to add the index number like `$users[0]->username`. If you use for loop, `$users->username` will work

Comment: please tell me where you dont understand , am just asking of help thats all

Comment: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array @user10971804 that is the error i got

Comment: `echo '<pre>',print_r($users);exit();` put this line after `$users`. Show the result here.

Answer (score 0):

I Think this code will help you i dont know the **username** field is exiest in which table so i will give the both options : may b this will works for you :

```
function GetactivationReq() 
{
  $settings = DB::table('settings')->where('id', 1)->first();    
  $users = DB::table('activationFee')->orderBy('id', 'desc')->get();
  foreach ($users as $row) {   
  $users_new   = DB::table('users')->where('id', $row->sender_id)->first();
  $receiver = DB::table('users')->where('id', $row->receiver_id)->first();
  $user = DB::table('userdetails')->where('userid', $row->sender_id)->first();
echo '<tr>
    <th><input type="checkbox" class="select-all" value="1"></th>
    <td>'.@$users->username.'</td>
    <td>'.@$users_new->username.'</td>
    <td>'.$user->accountname.'</td>
     <td>'.$receiver->username.'</td>
    <td>'.$settings->currency.''.$row->amount.'</td>
    <td>'.$row->payment_status.'</td>';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The code makes no sense but maybe this one can help:

```
function GetactivationReq()
{
    $settings = DB::table('settings')->where('id', 1)->first();
    $activationFees = DB::table('activationFee')->orderBy('id', 'desc')->get();
    foreach ($activationFees as $row) {
        $user = DB::table('users')->where('id', $row->sender_id)->first();
        $receiver = DB::table('users')->where('id', $row->receiver_id)->first();
        $userDetail = DB::table('userdetails')->where('userid', $row->sender_id)->first();
        echo '<tr>
    <th><input type="checkbox" class="select-all" value="1"></th>
    <td>' . $user->username . '</td>
    <td>' . $userDetail->accountname . '</td>
     <td>' . $receiver->username . '</td>
    <td>' . $settings->currency . '' . $row->amount . '</td>
    <td>' . $row->payment_status . '</td>';
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks alot guyss, i removed the $user->username and it worked

Comment: Please close your question by clicking the checkmark to the left of the answer that helped you most @UmehStanley